# Real time table AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, web

I'm working with the Twitter stream API. My server gets tweets from a concretes hashtags. For this I use a IO socket. The client receives the messages from the socket:

```js
socket.on('tweet', function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  $scope.streaming.push(msg);
});
```

You can see that also I push the messages in a table called streaming. In the HTML I have the ng-repeat directive:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
   <tr ng-repeat="tweet in streaming">
      <td>
         <div class="col-lg-2">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
            {{tweet}}
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The table starts empty and fills as the tweets come in. But in the page there aren't changes. The tweets only appear when I stop the server.

Why does it happen this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.on` callback runs out od angular digest cycle therefore you do not see results.

So you need to trigger digest cycle by calling `$apply` or `$timeout`.

For example:

```
socket.on('tweet', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
    $timeout(function(){
       $scope.streaming.push(msg);
    });        
});
```

Comment: I don't know your code but looks like by stopping server you triggest digest cycle too that leads to render your stuff